# Upgrade WebSphere 6.0 to 6.1

Tags: websphere

What updates are needed to upgrade WebSphere Windows 32-bit 6.0 to 6.1. I have 6.0 installation media, I'm trying to get a test environment to match a system at 6.1.0.31 patch level.

```
Installation Platform
------------------------------------------------------------

Name           IBM WebSphere Application Server
Version        6.0

Technology List
------------------------------------------------------------

BASE           installed

Installed Product
------------------------------------------------------------

Name           IBM WebSphere Application Server
Version        6.0.0.0
ID             BASE
Build Level    o0444.14
Build Date     11/5/04
```

I've found UpdateInstallers and fix packs on IBM FTP here, which includes one for 6.1.0.31:

ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/websphere/appserv/support/fixpacks
ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/software/websphere/appserv/support/tools/UpdateInstaller

However all the updates say they are not applicable. I think I need to apply this update 6.1.0-WS-WAS-WinX32-FP000003.pak
Extracting the PAK as a ZIP and reading maintenance.xml can see it needs version 6.1.0.0 as a minimum.

I couldn't see this scenario covered in PDF WebSphere Application Server v6 Migration Guide https://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246369.pdf

Is the only way to upgrade to 6.1 with complete installation media?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no upgrade between 6.0 and 6.1, they are separate releases.  You'd be doing a new install and a migration.

Of course both are hopelessly out of service and should not be used for any purpose in 2021.